# Expo PDFs - not able to view 1st and 3rd pages of 7 page PDF

Tags: android, react-native, pdf, mobile, expo

When viewing a 7 page PDF on a phone running Android 9, I'm not able to see the 1st and 3rd page of the PDF when it first loads. If I zoom in all the way, and then navigate through each page, then I'm able to see everything properly. Is this a known issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you supply expo snack with issue?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@trinet/rn-pdf-reader-js

Comment: In snack PDF file is  single page